# OpenCV Floodfill - pixel not well detected

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, flood-fill

I am looking to use OpenCV to fill a specific white areas delimited by black lines with another color. I use the floodfill function to do this, but it doesn't work perfectly. Some white pixels are not colored, the delimitation with the black lines being certainly badly detected.

Here is the code I am using (in C ++):

```
cv::Mat channel3Mat;
cv::cvtColor(imageMat, channel3Mat, cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR);
    
cv::floodFill(channel3Mat, cv::Point(x,y), cv::Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0), (cv::Rect*)0, cv::Scalar(16.0,16.0,16.0), cv::Scalar(16.0,16.0,16.0), 8);
```

[Initial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAsLX.png)

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHEE9.png)

I would like that there is no white pixel between the red fill color and the lines.

Comment: Have you tried changing the values of loDiff and upDiff in cv::floodFill? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga366aae45a6c1289b341d140839f18717

Comment: Threshold your image first, that will get rid of the antialiasing.

Comment: I try to threshold my image first and it's working :) Thanks